# How to place abstract before first section in org-mode's LaTeX-export

Tags: org-mode

Here's another newbie question about org-mode's LaTeX export:

Given this file `test.org`

```
#+BEGIN_abstract
asdf, or whatever I want to write in the abstract ...
#+END_abstract

* Introduction
  This is my inroduction ...
```

an export via

```
$ emacs --batch --visit=./test.org --funcall org-export-as-latex
```

Produces this error:

```
unbalanced begin/end_abstract blocks with "#+BEGIN_abstract
"
```

When I switch the abstract and introduction in the file, everything works fine:

```
* Introduction

#+BEGIN_abstract
asdf, or whatever I want to write in the abstract ...
#+END_abstract
```

But then, the abstract comes *within* the introduction. However, I need it to be *before* the introduction.

How can I achieve this?

I'm running Emacs 23 on Ubuntu 12.04.

**UPDATE** 
following the advice by @giordano, I created a file emacs_setup.el:

```
(defun org-export-latex-no-toc (depth)  
    (when depth
      (format "%% Org-mode is exporting headings to %s levels.\n"
              depth)))
(setq org-export-latex-format-toc-function 'org-export-latex-no-toc)
```

And changed my org file to

```
#+TITLE: My Document
#+AUTHOR: Andreas H.

#+LATEX: \tableofcontents
#+LATEX: \listoftables
#+LATEX: \listoffigures

#+begin_abstract
  asdf, or whatever I want to write in the abstract ...
#+end_abstract

* Introduction
```

But when calling

```
$ emacs --batch -l emacs_setup.el --visit=test.org --funcall org-export-as-latex
```

I get the exact same error.

Comment: See http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#sec-11-1 Does it help?  Perhaps you need also to set a title before the abstract.

Comment: no, it doesn't help. See updated question.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, with Emacs 24 and org-mode 8 I don't get that error.

Comment: maybe a change in org-mode 8? I'll try installing emacs24 with the new org-mode and see if the error persists.

Comment: @giordano Thanks for your help, installing Emacs 24 and org-mode 8.0.7 indeed solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use the LaTeX code directly for this result

```
\begin{abstract}

This is the abstract.

\end{abstract}


* Introduction

  This is the introduction.
```